# Lag in the framer motion animations

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, framer-motion

I'm bulding a personal porfolio website in reactjs.

I've have animated tabs which is connected to state(currentCategory) everytime it changes triggers a useState function. which fetch the data from firestore and store to localState(projectData). I'm using framer motion and while going throught this process animation lags I don't know why.

If someone can show his/her expertise to help me solve this problem that would be great.

Here is the code
project-section.js

```
import Cards from "./cards";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { projectFirestore} from "../firebase/firebase-core";
import Tabs from "./tabs";


let tabs = [
    { id: "featured", label: "Feature" },
    { id: "all projects", label: "All Projects" },
    { id: "logo animation", label: "Logo Animation" },
    { id: "animated explainer", label: "Animated Explainers" },
    { id: "app promos", label: "App Promos" },
];

export default function ProjectSection() {

    const [projectData, setProjectData] = useState([])

    const [currentCategory, setCurrentCategory] = useState(tabs[0].id);

    const[isPending, setIsPending] = useState(false)
    const[error, setError] = useState()

    
    useEffect(function () {
        setIsPending(true)
        let ref = projectFirestore.collection('projects');
        
        let query;
       
        
        if(currentCategory === "all projects"){
            query = ref;
        }else{
            query = ref.where('projectCategory', 'array-contains-any', [currentCategory]);
        }

        if(projectData){
            setProjectData(null)
        }
        
        console.log("effect runs");
        
        const unsubscribe = query.onSnapshot((snapshot) =>{
            if(snapshot.empty){
                setError("No Projects")
                setIsPending(false)
            }
            else{
                snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) =>{
                    setProjectData([doc.data()])
                })
                setIsPending(false)
                if(error){
                    setError(null)
                }
            }
        })
       
        return unsubscribe;

    }, [currentCategory])
    console.log("rendered");
    return (
        <div className="mt-16">
            <Tabs 
                tabs={tabs}
                projectData={projectData}
                // setFilteredData={setFilteredData} 
                currentCategory={currentCategory} 
                setCurrentCategory={setCurrentCategory} />

                <div className="divider"></div>

            {/* Cards */}
            <div className="flex mt-4 justify-center">
                <div className="max-w-5xl p-4 grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 gap-3 md:gap-4">
                    {
                        projectData &&  projectData.map((data, index) => {
                            return <Cards key={index} ProjectID={data.id} projectName={data.projectName} thumbnail={data.thumbnailURL} alt={data.projectName} />
                        })
                    }
                    
                </div>
                {isPending && <p>Loading...</p>}
                {error && <p>{error}</p>}
            </div>
            
        </div>
    );
}
```

Tabs.js

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion";


export default function Tabs({tabs, currentCategory, setCurrentCategory, projectData, setFilteredData}) {
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="flex space-x-1 justify-center overflow-x-scroll">
                {tabs.map((tab) => (
                    <button
                        key={tab.id}
                        onClick={() => setCurrentCategory(tab.id)}
                        className={`${
                            currentCategory === tab.id ? "" : "hover:text-white/60"
                        } relative rounded-md px-3 py-1.5 text-sm inline-block font-medium text-neutral outline-sky-400 transition focus-visible:outline-2`}
                        
                    >
                    {currentCategory === tab.id && (
                        <motion.span
                            layoutId="bubble"
                            className="absolute inset-0 z-[-1] text-white bg-secondary"
                            style={{ borderRadius: 9999 }}
                            transition={{ type: "spring", bounce: 0.2, duration: 0.2 }}
                        />
                    )}
                    {tab.label}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
        </div>   
    )
}
```

I want the animation to work flawlessly.